# tickValues in d3 not working as expected

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to make a simple graph where I only have one tick value, at the max of the y axis. I actually had this working, but I moved things around because I needed to have things contained within a function and even though I did not change this code it is not working as expected.

I've been staring at it for over an hour and would appreciate a second set of eyes.

First, some code:

```
function AlmViz() {
    ... 

    this.x = d3.time.scale();
    this.x.range([0, this.width]);

    this.y = d3.scale.linear();
    this.y.range([this.height, 0]);
}

function loadData(viz) {
    ... 

    viz.yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .orient("left")
        .tickSize(0)
        .tickValues([d3.max(viz.y.domain())])   // only one tick at max
        .tickFormat(d3.format(",d"));


    viz.y.domain([0, d3.max(level_data, function(d) { return d[category.name]; })]);

    ...
    viz.svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(viz.yAxis);
}

var viz = new AlmViz();
loadData(viz);
```

However, the y-axis is wonky. The tick has the right text, but it gets placed in the wrong location.

```
<g class="y axis">
     <g class="tick major" style="opacity: 1;" transform="translate(0,7016)">
         <line x2="0" y2="0"></line>
         <text x="-3" y="0" dy=".32em" style="text-anchor: end;">7,016</text>
     </g>
     <path class="domain" d="M0,0H0V1H0"></path>
</g>
```

The problem is **transform="translate(0,7016)**. Does anybody know how to fix it?

I should note, I have virtually the same code in an earlier iteration, and it was working correctly. See https://github.com/jalperin/almviz/blob/d3/alm.js for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the scale to the axis, thusly

```
viz.yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .orient("left")
    .scale(viz.y)
    .tickSize(0)
    .tickValues([d3.max(viz.y.domain())])   // only one tick at max
    .tickFormat(d3.format(",d"));
```

Comment: I've tried that too, but it makes no difference. Any other ideas?

Comment: What does your data look like? Did you verify that the domain of `viz.y` is set correctly?

Comment: the dat looks good. From the console: viz.y returns
function i(n){return a(n)}  and viz.y.domain()
returns [0, 7016]

Comment: You can see the full code here: https://github.com/jalperin/almviz/blob/d3/alm.js including the sample data https://github.com/jalperin/almviz/blob/d3/alm.json

Comment: You don't seem to be setting the output range on `viz.y`.

Comment: it gets set in the constructor AlmViz()

Comment: viz.y.range() returns: [250, 0]

Comment: Ok, so just for a sanity check -- does it work if you comment `tickValues()`?

Comment: basically, a bunch of ticks all get placed in the same place, only a couple with values: http://cl.ly/OSQO

Comment: Ah. You haven't assigned a scale to that axis.

Comment: line 61:  this.y = d3.scale.linear();

Comment: I mean you haven't assigned that scale to the axis. You do this in line 85 for the x axis, but not for the y axis.

Comment: ah! that's it! could you update your answer with this info? i'll accept it.

Comment: Updated/changed entirely ;)

Comment: Thanks so much. So easy to miss things when you stare at them for too long.